# Is there a way to log all incoming SFCC OCAPI requests?

Tags: salesforce-commerce-cloud

Anybody knows if there is already a way to log all SFCC OCAPI calls, similar to the web service logs?

[This unanswered question](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdh7zUAB/need-to-access-request-logs-for-all-ocapi-calls) let's me think, there is no standard way, but maybe somebody knows of some workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think with custom development you should be able to achieve it. Use the OCAPI hooks, and output logging information in the before hooks for each endpoint you are calling.